# How to Use forloop inside the list of sqlparameter?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, desktop-application

How to add my data gridview value into database i m using dal my code is this

```
Dim list As New List(Of SqlParameter)

For each row as DataGridView In DataGridView1.Rows
    If row.cell(0).value isnot nothing
        Qry="insert into sale1(Description)values(@1)"
        With list
           .add(new Sqlparameter("@1",row.cells(2).value)
        End with
    End if
Next
```

Comment: It should be `For each row as DataGridViewRow`.

Comment: Why are you using a `List(Of SqlParameter)`?

Comment: Why use a loop at all? If you bind a `DataTable` to the grid then you can just make a single call to `Update` on a data adapter to save the lot.

Comment: I m make the data accesslayer and use here as instance..

Comment: Please explain with code thanx

Comment: A data access layer does not refer to any User Interface items such as a DataGridView and a the User Interface show not refer to any database objects like an SqlParameter.

Comment: Why the `With`? There is only a single item in the `With`; it seems easier to just  do `list.add`.

Comment: Why set the value of `Qry` to the same value over and over in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do as @jmcilhinney suggested in comments (the best way), this should work as closest to the code you provided but it does not separate database code form user interface code.

The idea is to add the parameter once outside the loop and then just change the value in the loop. I had to guess at the datatype and size of the parameter. Please check your database and correct the code.

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into sale1 (Description)values(@1)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300)
        cn.Open()
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If row.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                cmd.Parameters("@1").Value = row.Cells(2).Value
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

To separate the code...

```
Private Sub UICode()
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
            lst.Add(row.Cells(2).Value.ToString)
        End If
    Next
    UpdateDatabase(lst)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateDatabase(lst As List(Of String))
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into sale1 (Description)values(@1)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300)
        cn.Open()
        For Each s As String In lst
            cmd.Parameters("@1").Value = s
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx for valueable reply or ans

Comment: I m trying to say how to make to this code using class connection.. its nessesary to write two time connection string and make 2 coonection thanx

Comment: No, you can have a variable Private ConString = "????" at the class level and use the variable to pass to the constructor of the Connection. Don't use a class connection. Keep you connections local to the methods where they are used so they can be closed and disposed. This is important to allow the connection to return to the pool and prevent memory leaks.